# Synchronize contacts between local Outlook installation and Outlook.com / Microsoft Cloud

Tags: microsoft-outlook, contacts, microsoft-outlook-365, outlook.com

I have installed Outlook 365 locally and want to keep this local installation as the master. Further, I want all my contacts to be available in Outlook.com / Microsoft cloud in order to synchronize with various devices.

How can I get my contacts from the local Outlook installation to Outlook.com / Microsoft cloud?

(CSV is not an option as I want this to happen automatically.)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If it is useful, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.

Answer (score 0):

To **sync your contacts to Outlook.com**, you just need to configure your Outlook.com account as **Exchange** in Outlook 365 desktop client.
[image]

More information about Microsoft Cloud:

[Sync your account in Outlook to the Microsoft Cloud](https://products.support.services.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-your-account-in-outlook-to-the-microsoft-cloud-985f9e19-d308-4e85-9d1d-0c6f32f8e981)